# Which JAX - RS version is compatible with Java 1.6?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jdk6

Unable to find this information. I have a project built using Java 1.6. Now I need to consume the rest web API using JAX - RS. Which version should I download ?

Answer (score 1):

Until version 2.6, Jersey was compiled with Java SE 6.Anything after 2.6 is compiled with Java 7

[jaxrs-ri-2.6.jar](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.6/)

If it doesn't work with the jaxrs-ri-2.6.jar jar, try and download the jaxrs-ri-2.6.tar.gz from the same link above. Unzip it and add all the jars from every directory